# Error estimation for curve fitting and sample means using Python and scipy

Tags: python, scipy

**A)** I have a set of samples; each sample consists of measured times `t_arr`, measurement values `y_arr` and estimated measurement errors `y_err_arr`. It is assumed that the times are free of any error.

**B)** Then I have a model for y(t), defined as

```
def func_y(t, a, b, c):
    return ...
```

where `a, b, c` are three parameters that are fitted using

```
pfit, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func_y, t_arr, y_arr)
a, b, c = pfit
```

The errors for the fitted parameters `a, b, c` are estimated using

```
a_err, b_err, c_err = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(pcov))
```

**C)** I have several such samples (A), therefore several fits (B) for the parameters, and therefore a sample mean and a sample error for each parameter. The sample mean is just

```
a_mean = np.mean(a_arr)    # b_mean, c_mean ...
```

where `a_arr, b_arr, c_arr` contain all sample results from (B).

I could also calculate the sample errors using standard methods from `numpy` or `scipy`, but I don't know how to take errors from (B) into account.

In essence, for each step (A), (B), (C) I know how to treat the errors, but I don't know how to propagate errors from (A) to (B) to (C).

**Questions**

1. How do I take the measurement errors `y_err_arr` into account when fitting the curve y(t) and therefore the parameters `a, b, c` in (B)?
2. How do I take the errors from (B) into account when calculating the errors for the sample means(C))

A concrete application is to fit the function

```
def damped_osci(t, t_0, y_0, Omega, beta):
    # t_0, y_0, Omega, beta are the parameters to be fitted  
    delta = np.arctan(beta / Omega)    
    return y_0 * np.exp(-beta * (t - t_0)) * np.cos(Omega * (t - t_0) - delta) / np.cos(delta)
```

with constant error

```
y_err = 0.0005    # as a starting point, instead of a numpy array
```

for the input data

```
time_arr = np.array([0.01000000, 0.02000000, 0.03000000, 0.04000000, 0.05000000, 0.06000000, 0.07000000, 0.08000000, 0.09000000, 0.10000000, 0.11000000, 0.12000000, 0.13000000, 0.14000000, 0.15000000, 0.16000000, 0.17000000, 0.18000000, 0.19000000, 0.20000000, 0.21000000, 0.22000000, 0.23000000, 0.24000000, 0.25000000, 0.26000000, 0.27000000, 0.28000000, 0.29000000, 0.30000000, 0.31000000, 0.32000000, 0.33000000, 0.34000000, 0.35000000, 0.36000000, 0.37000000, 0.38000000, 0.39000000, 0.40000000, 0.41000000, 0.42000000, 0.43000000, 0.44000000, 0.45000000, 0.46000000, 0.47000000, 0.48000000, 0.49000000, 0.50000000, 0.51000000, 0.52000000, 0.53000000, 0.54000000, 0.55000000, 0.56000000, 0.57000000, 0.58000000, 0.59000000, 0.60000000, 0.61000000, 0.62000000, 0.63000000, 0.64000000, 0.65000000, 0.66000000, 0.67000000, 0.68000000, 0.69000000, 0.70000000, 0.71000000, 0.72000000, 0.73000000, 0.74000000, 0.75000000, 0.76000000, 0.77000000, 0.78000000, 0.79000000, 0.80000000, 0.81000000, 0.82000000, 0.83000000, 0.84000000, 0.85000000, 0.86000000, 0.87000000, 0.88000000, 0.89000000, 0.90000000, 0.91000000, 0.92000000, 0.93000000, 0.94000000, 0.95000000, 0.96000000, 0.97000000, 0.98000000, 0.99000000, 1.00000000, 1.01000000, 1.02000000, 1.03000000, 1.04000000, 1.05000000, 1.06000000, 1.07000000, 1.08000000, 1.09000000, 1.10000000, 1.11000000, 1.12000000, 1.13000000, 1.14000000, 1.15000000, 1.16000000, 1.17000000, 1.18000000, 1.19000000, 1.20000000, 1.21000000, 1.22000000, 1.23000000, 1.24000000, 1.25000000, 1.26000000, 1.27000000, 1.28000000, 1.29000000, 1.30000000, 1.31000000, 1.32000000, 1.33000000, 1.34000000, 1.35000000, 1.36000000, 1.37000000, 1.38000000, 1.39000000, 1.40000000, 1.41000000, 1.42000000, 1.43000000, 1.44000000, 1.45000000, 1.46000000, 1.47000000, 1.48000000, 1.49000000, 1.50000000, 1.51000000, 1.52000000, 1.53000000, 1.54000000, 1.55000000, 1.56000000, 1.57000000, 1.58000000, 1.59000000, 1.60000000, 1.61000000, 1.62000000, 1.63000000, 1.64000000, 1.65000000, 1.66000000, 1.67000000, 1.68000000, 1.69000000, 1.70000000, 1.71000000, 1.72000000, 1.73000000, 1.74000000, 1.75000000, 1.76000000, 1.77000000, 1.78000000, 1.79000000, 1.80000000, 1.81000000, 1.82000000, 1.83000000, 1.84000000, 1.85000000, 1.86000000, 1.87000000, 1.88000000, 1.89000000, 1.90000000, 1.91000000, 1.92000000, 1.93000000, 1.94000000, 1.95000000, 1.96000000, 1.97000000, 1.98000000, 1.99000000, 2.00000000, 2.01000000, 2.02000000, 2.03000000, 2.04000000, 2.05000000, 2.06000000, 2.07000000, 2.08000000, 2.09000000, 2.10000000, 2.11000000, 2.12000000, 2.13000000, 2.14000000, 2.15000000, 2.16000000, 2.17000000, 2.18000000, 2.19000000, 2.20000000, 2.21000000, 2.22000000, 2.23000000, 2.24000000, 2.25000000, 2.26000000, 2.27000000, 2.28000000, 2.29000000, 2.30000000, 2.31000000, 2.32000000, 2.33000000, 2.34000000, 2.35000000, 2.36000000, 2.37000000, 2.38000000, 2.39000000, 2.40000000, 2.41000000, 2.42000000, 2.43000000, 2.44000000, 2.45000000, 2.46000000, 2.47000000, 2.48000000, 2.49000000, 2.50000000, 2.51000000, 2.52000000, 2.53000000, 2.54000000, 2.55000000, 2.56000000, 2.57000000, 2.58000000, 2.59000000, 2.60000000, 2.61000000, 2.62000000, 2.63000000, 2.64000000, 2.65000000, 2.66000000, 2.67000000, 2.68000000, 2.69000000, 2.70000000, 2.71000000, 2.72000000, 2.73000000, 2.74000000, 2.75000000, 2.76000000, 2.77000000, 2.78000000, 2.79000000, 2.80000000, 2.81000000, 2.82000000, 2.83000000, 2.84000000, 2.85000000, 2.86000000, 2.87000000, 2.88000000, 2.89000000, 2.90000000, 2.91000000, 2.92000000, 2.93000000, 2.94000000, 2.95000000, 2.96000000, 2.97000000, 2.98000000, 2.99000000, 3.00000000, 3.01000000, 3.02000000, 3.03000000, 3.04000000, 3.05000000, 3.06000000, 3.07000000, 3.08000000, 3.09000000, 3.10000000, 3.11000000, 3.12000000, 3.13000000, 3.14000000, 3.15000000, 3.16000000, 3.17000000, 3.18000000, 3.19000000, 3.20000000, 3.21000000, 3.22000000, 3.23000000, 3.24000000, 3.25000000, 3.26000000, 3.27000000, 3.28000000, 3.29000000, 3.30000000, 3.31000000, 3.32000000, 3.33000000, 3.34000000, 3.35000000, 3.36000000, 3.37000000, 3.38000000, 3.39000000, 3.40000000, 3.41000000, 3.42000000, 3.43000000, 3.44000000, 3.45000000, 3.46000000, 3.47000000, 3.48000000, 3.49000000, 3.50000000, 3.51000000, 3.52000000, 3.53000000, 3.54000000, 3.55000000, 3.56000000, 3.57000000, 3.58000000, 3.59000000, 3.60000000, 3.61000000, 3.62000000, 3.63000000, 3.64000000, 3.65000000, 3.66000000, 3.67000000, 3.68000000, 3.69000000, 3.70000000, 3.71000000, 3.72000000, 3.73000000, 3.74000000, 3.75000000, 3.76000000, 3.77000000, 3.78000000, 3.79000000, 3.80000000, 3.81000000, 3.82000000, 3.83000000, 3.84000000, 3.85000000, 3.86000000, 3.87000000, 3.88000000, 3.89000000, 3.90000000, 3.91000000, 3.92000000, 3.93000000, 3.94000000, 3.95000000, 3.96000000, 3.97000000, 3.98000000, 3.99000000, 4.00000000, 4.01000000, 4.02000000, 4.03000000, 4.04000000, 4.05000000, 4.06000000, 4.07000000, 4.08000000, 4.09000000, 4.10000000, 4.11000000, 4.12000000, 4.13000000, 4.14000000, 4.15000000, 4.16000000, 4.17000000, 4.18000000, 4.19000000, 4.20000000, 4.21000000, 4.22000000, 4.23000000, 4.24000000, 4.25000000, 4.26000000, 4.27000000, 4.28000000, 4.29000000, 4.30000000, 4.31000000, 4.32000000, 4.33000000, 4.34000000, 4.35000000, 4.36000000, 4.37000000, 4.38000000, 4.39200000, 4.40200000, 4.41200000, 4.42200000, 4.43200000, 4.44200000, 4.45200000, 4.46200000, 4.47200000, 4.48200000, 4.49200000, 4.50200000, 4.51200000, 4.52200000, 4.53200000, 4.54200000, 4.55200000, 4.56200000, 4.57200000, 4.58200000, 4.59200000, 4.60200000, 4.61200000, 4.62200000, 4.63200000, 4.64200000, 4.65200000, 4.66200000, 4.67200000, 4.68200000, 4.69200000, 4.70200000, 4.71200000, 4.72200000, 4.73200000, 4.74200000, 4.75200000, 4.76200000, 4.77200000, 4.78200000, 4.79200000, 4.80200000, 4.81200000, 4.82200000, 4.83200000, 4.84200000, 4.85200000, 4.86200000, 4.87200000, 4.88200000, 4.89200000, 4.90200000, 4.91200000, 4.92200000, 4.93200000, 4.94200000, 4.95200000, 4.96200000, 4.97200000, 4.98200000, 4.99200000, 5.00200000, 5.01200000, 5.02200000, 5.03200000, 5.04200000, 5.05200000, 5.06200000, 5.07200000, 5.08200000, 5.09200000, 5.10200000, 5.11200000, 5.12200000, 5.13200000, 5.14200000, 5.15200000, 5.16200000, 5.17200000, 5.18200000, 5.19200000, 5.20200000, 5.21200000, 5.22200000, 5.23200000, 5.24200000, 5.25200000, 5.26200000, 5.27200000, 5.28200000, 5.29200000, 5.30200000])
y_arr = np.array([0.00166700, 0.01167000, 0.02167000, 0.03167000, 0.04167000, 0.05167000, 0.06167000, 0.07167000, 0.08167000, 0.09167000, 0.10170000, 0.11170000, 0.12170000, 0.13170000, 0.14170000, 0.15170000, 0.16170000, 0.17170000, 0.18170000, 0.19170000, 0.20170000, 0.21170000, 0.22170000, 0.23170000, 0.24170000, 0.25170000, 0.26170000, 0.27170000, 0.28170000, 0.29170000, 0.30170000, 0.31170000, 0.32170000, 0.33170000, 0.34170000, 0.35170000, 0.36170000, 0.37170000, 0.38170000, 0.39170000, 0.40170000, 0.41170000, 0.42170000, 0.43170000, 0.44170000, 0.45170000, 0.46170000, 0.47170000, 0.48170000, 0.49170000, 0.50170000, 0.51170000, 0.52170000, 0.53170000, 0.54170000, 0.55170000, 0.56170000, 0.57170000, 0.58170000, 0.59170000, 0.60170000, 0.61170000, 0.62170000, 0.63170000, 0.64170000, 0.65170000, 0.66170000, 0.67170000, 0.68170000, 0.69170000, 0.70170000, 0.71170000, 0.72170000, 0.73170000, 0.74170000, 0.75170000, 0.76170000, 0.77170000, 0.78170000, 0.79170000, 0.80170000, 0.81170000, 0.82170000, 0.83170000, 0.84170000, 0.85170000, 0.86170000, 0.87170000, 0.88170000, 0.89170000, 0.90170000, 0.91170000, 0.92170000, 0.93170000, 0.94170000, 0.95170000, 0.96170000, 0.97170000, 0.98170000, 0.99170000, 1.00200000, 1.01200000, 1.02200000, 1.03200000, 1.04200000, 1.05200000, 1.06200000, 1.07200000, 1.08200000, 1.09200000, 1.10200000, 1.11200000, 1.12200000, 1.13200000, 1.14200000, 1.15200000, 1.16200000, 1.17200000, 1.18200000, 1.19200000, 1.20200000, 1.21200000, 1.22200000, 1.23200000, 1.24200000, 1.25200000, 1.26200000, 1.27200000, 1.28200000, 1.29200000, 1.30200000, 1.31200000, 1.32200000, 1.33200000, 1.34200000, 1.35200000, 1.36200000, 1.37200000, 1.38200000, 1.39200000, 1.40200000, 1.41200000, 1.42200000, 1.43200000, 1.44200000, 1.45200000, 1.46200000, 1.47200000, 1.48200000, 1.49200000, 1.50200000, 1.51200000, 1.52200000, 1.53200000, 1.54200000, 1.55200000, 1.56200000, 1.57200000, 1.58200000, 1.59200000, 1.60200000, 1.61200000, 1.62200000, 1.63200000, 1.64200000, 1.65200000, 1.66200000, 1.67200000, 1.68200000, 1.69200000, 1.70200000, 1.71200000, 1.72200000, 1.73200000, 1.74200000, 1.75200000, 1.76200000, 1.77200000, 1.78200000, 1.79200000, 1.80200000, 1.81200000, 1.82200000, 1.83200000, 1.84200000, 1.85200000, 1.86200000, 1.87200000, 1.88200000, 1.89200000, 1.90200000, 1.91200000, 1.92200000, 1.93200000, 1.94200000, 1.95200000, 1.96200000, 1.97200000, 1.98200000, 1.99200000, 2.00200000, 2.01200000, 2.02200000, 2.03200000, 2.04200000, 2.05200000, 2.06200000, 2.07200000, 2.08200000, 2.09200000, 2.10200000, 2.11200000, 2.12200000, 2.13200000, 2.14200000, 2.15200000, 2.16200000, 2.17200000, 2.18200000, 2.19200000, 2.20200000, 2.21200000, 2.22200000, 2.23200000, 2.24200000, 2.25200000, 2.26200000, 2.27200000, 2.28200000, 2.29200000, 2.30200000, 2.31200000, 2.32200000, 2.33200000, 2.34200000, 2.35200000, 2.36200000, 2.37200000, 2.38200000, 2.39200000, 2.40200000, 2.41200000, 2.42200000, 2.43200000, 2.44200000, 2.45200000, 2.46200000, 2.47200000, 2.48200000, 2.49200000, 2.50200000, 2.51200000, 2.52200000, 2.53200000, 2.54200000, 2.55200000, 2.56200000, 2.57200000, 2.58200000, 2.59200000, 2.60200000, 2.61200000, 2.62200000, 2.63200000, 2.64200000, 2.65200000, 2.66200000, 2.67200000, 2.68200000, 2.69200000, 2.70200000, 2.71200000, 2.72200000, 2.73200000, 2.74200000, 2.75200000, 2.76200000, 2.77200000, 2.78200000, 2.79200000, 2.80200000, 2.81200000, 2.82200000, 2.83200000, 2.84200000, 2.85200000, 2.86200000, 2.87200000, 2.88200000, 2.89200000, 2.90200000, 2.91200000, 2.92200000, 2.93200000, 2.94200000, 2.95200000, 2.96200000, 2.97200000, 2.98200000, 2.99200000, 3.00200000, 3.01200000, 3.02200000, 3.03200000, 3.04200000, 3.05200000, 3.06200000, 3.07200000, 3.08200000, 3.09200000, 3.10200000, 3.11200000, 3.12200000, 3.13200000, 3.14200000, 3.15200000, 3.16200000, 3.17200000, 3.18200000, 3.19200000, 3.20200000, 3.21200000, 3.22200000, 3.23200000, 3.24200000, 3.25200000, 3.26200000, 3.27200000, 3.28200000, 3.29200000, 3.30200000, 3.31200000, 3.32200000, 3.33200000, 3.34200000, 3.35200000, 3.36200000, 3.37200000, 3.38200000, 3.39200000, 3.40200000, 3.41200000, 3.42200000, 3.43200000, 3.44200000, 3.45200000, 3.46200000, 3.47200000, 3.48200000, 3.49200000, 3.50200000, 3.51200000, 3.52200000, 3.53200000, 3.54200000, 3.55200000, 3.56200000, 3.57200000, 3.58200000, 3.59200000, 3.60200000, 3.61200000, 3.62200000, 3.63200000, 3.64200000, 3.65200000, 3.66200000, 3.67200000, 3.68200000, 3.69200000, 3.70200000, 3.71200000, 3.72200000, 3.73200000, 3.74200000, 3.75200000, 3.76200000, 3.77200000, 3.78200000, 3.79200000, 3.80200000, 3.81200000, 3.82200000, 3.83200000, 3.84200000, 3.85200000, 3.86200000, 3.87200000, 3.88200000, 3.89200000, 3.90200000, 3.91200000, 3.92200000, 3.93300000, 3.94300000, 3.95300000, 3.96300000, 3.97300000, 3.98300000, 3.99300000, 4.00300000, 4.01300000, 4.02300000, 4.03300000, 4.04300000, 4.05300000, 4.06300000, 4.07300000, 4.08300000, 4.09300000, 4.10300000, 4.11300000, 4.12300000, 4.13300000, 4.14300000, 4.15300000, 4.16300000, 4.17300000, 4.18300000, 4.19300000, 4.20300000, 4.21300000, 4.22300000, 4.23300000, 4.24300000, 4.25300000, 4.26300000, 4.27300000, 4.28300000, 4.29300000, 4.30300000, 4.31300000, 4.32300000, 4.33300000, 4.34300000, 4.35300000, 4.36300000, 4.37300000, 4.38300000, 4.39300000, 4.40300000, 4.41300000, 4.42300000, 4.43300000, 4.44300000, 4.45300000, 4.46300000, 4.47300000, 4.48300000, 4.49300000, 4.50300000, 4.51300000, 4.52300000, 4.53300000, 4.54300000, 4.55300000, 4.56300000, 4.57300000, 4.58300000, 4.59300000, 4.60300000, 4.61300000, 4.62300000, 4.63300000, 4.64300000, 4.65300000, 4.66300000, 4.67300000, 4.68300000, 4.69300000, 4.70300000, 4.71300000, 4.72300000, 4.73300000, 4.74300000, 4.75300000, 4.76300000, 4.77300000, 4.78300000, 4.79300000, 4.80300000, 4.81300000, 4.82300000, 4.83300000, 4.84300000, 4.85300000, 4.86300000, 4.87300000, 4.88300000, 4.89300000, 4.90300000, 4.91300000, 4.92300000, 4.93300000, 4.94300000, 4.95300000, 4.96300000, 4.97300000, 4.98300000, 4.99300000, 5.00300000, 5.01300000, 5.02300000, 5.03300000, 5.04300000, 5.05300000, 5.06300000, 5.07300000, 5.08300000, 5.09300000, 5.10300000, 5.11300000, 5.12300000, 5.13300000, 5.14300000, 5.15300000, 5.16300000, 5.17300000, 5.18300000, 5.19300000])
```

Comment: Since you have several samples sets and you're taking the mean of their fit parameters, why not just fit all of them together in one step?

Comment: Because they have been sampled at different, non-equidistant times, and with different initial conditions. So there are two additional fit parameters, namely a shift in t and the scale of y, which differ between the samples. In order to normalize all samples I first have to fit at least these two parameters, which brings my question back through the backdoor.

Comment: It's not about my code, it's about the conceptual question how to glue these steps together, or whether there are libraries with built-in functions solving this problem.

Comment: The question remains: given the error for (A), fitting of the function and parameters for (B), and several such runs, how can an error propagation from (A) to (B) to (C) work? The individual steps are clear and run without problems.

Comment: Question updated accordingly.

Comment: I've shown how to pass in sigma. For the other question of how to wrangle different covariance matrices from multiple series fits, that's more a question for stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the error into `sigma`. Here it's shown as an array whose mean is 0.5 so that it's visually significant on the graph.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def damped_osci(t: np.ndarray, t_0: float, y_0: float, Omega: float, beta: float):
    # t_0, y_0, Omega, beta are the parameters to be fitted
    delta = np.arctan(beta / Omega)
    return (
        y_0
        * np.exp(-beta * (t - t_0))
        * np.cos(Omega * (t - t_0) - delta)
        / np.cos(delta)
    )


time_arr = np.array([0.01000000, 0.02000000, 0.03000000, 0.04000000, 0.05000000, 0.06000000, 0.07000000, 0.08000000, 0.09000000, 0.10000000, 0.11000000, 0.12000000, 0.13000000, 0.14000000, 0.15000000, 0.16000000, 0.17000000, 0.18000000, 0.19000000, 0.20000000, 0.21000000, 0.22000000, 0.23000000, 0.24000000, 0.25000000, 0.26000000, 0.27000000, 0.28000000, 0.29000000, 0.30000000, 0.31000000, 0.32000000, 0.33000000, 0.34000000, 0.35000000, 0.36000000, 0.37000000, 0.38000000, 0.39000000, 0.40000000, 0.41000000, 0.42000000, 0.43000000, 0.44000000, 0.45000000, 0.46000000, 0.47000000, 0.48000000, 0.49000000, 0.50000000, 0.51000000, 0.52000000, 0.53000000, 0.54000000, 0.55000000, 0.56000000, 0.57000000, 0.58000000, 0.59000000, 0.60000000, 0.61000000, 0.62000000, 0.63000000, 0.64000000, 0.65000000, 0.66000000, 0.67000000, 0.68000000, 0.69000000, 0.70000000, 0.71000000, 0.72000000, 0.73000000, 0.74000000, 0.75000000, 0.76000000, 0.77000000, 0.78000000, 0.79000000, 0.80000000, 0.81000000, 0.82000000, 0.83000000, 0.84000000, 0.85000000, 0.86000000, 0.87000000, 0.88000000, 0.89000000, 0.90000000, 0.91000000, 0.92000000, 0.93000000, 0.94000000, 0.95000000, 0.96000000, 0.97000000, 0.98000000, 0.99000000, 1.00000000, 1.01000000, 1.02000000, 1.03000000, 1.04000000, 1.05000000, 1.06000000, 1.07000000, 1.08000000, 1.09000000, 1.10000000, 1.11000000, 1.12000000, 1.13000000, 1.14000000, 1.15000000, 1.16000000, 1.17000000, 1.18000000, 1.19000000, 1.20000000, 1.21000000, 1.22000000, 1.23000000, 1.24000000, 1.25000000, 1.26000000, 1.27000000, 1.28000000, 1.29000000, 1.30000000, 1.31000000, 1.32000000, 1.33000000, 1.34000000, 1.35000000, 1.36000000, 1.37000000, 1.38000000, 1.39000000, 1.40000000, 1.41000000, 1.42000000, 1.43000000, 1.44000000, 1.45000000, 1.46000000, 1.47000000, 1.48000000, 1.49000000, 1.50000000, 1.51000000, 1.52000000, 1.53000000, 1.54000000, 1.55000000, 1.56000000, 1.57000000, 1.58000000, 1.59000000, 1.60000000, 1.61000000, 1.62000000, 1.63000000, 1.64000000, 1.65000000, 1.66000000, 1.67000000, 1.68000000, 1.69000000, 1.70000000, 1.71000000, 1.72000000, 1.73000000, 1.74000000, 1.75000000, 1.76000000, 1.77000000, 1.78000000, 1.79000000, 1.80000000, 1.81000000, 1.82000000, 1.83000000, 1.84000000, 1.85000000, 1.86000000, 1.87000000, 1.88000000, 1.89000000, 1.90000000, 1.91000000, 1.92000000, 1.93000000, 1.94000000, 1.95000000, 1.96000000, 1.97000000, 1.98000000, 1.99000000, 2.00000000, 2.01000000, 2.02000000, 2.03000000, 2.04000000, 2.05000000, 2.06000000, 2.07000000, 2.08000000, 2.09000000, 2.10000000, 2.11000000, 2.12000000, 2.13000000, 2.14000000, 2.15000000, 2.16000000, 2.17000000, 2.18000000, 2.19000000, 2.20000000, 2.21000000, 2.22000000, 2.23000000, 2.24000000, 2.25000000, 2.26000000, 2.27000000, 2.28000000, 2.29000000, 2.30000000, 2.31000000, 2.32000000, 2.33000000, 2.34000000, 2.35000000, 2.36000000, 2.37000000, 2.38000000, 2.39000000, 2.40000000, 2.41000000, 2.42000000, 2.43000000, 2.44000000, 2.45000000, 2.46000000, 2.47000000, 2.48000000, 2.49000000, 2.50000000, 2.51000000, 2.52000000, 2.53000000, 2.54000000, 2.55000000, 2.56000000, 2.57000000, 2.58000000, 2.59000000, 2.60000000, 2.61000000, 2.62000000, 2.63000000, 2.64000000, 2.65000000, 2.66000000, 2.67000000, 2.68000000, 2.69000000, 2.70000000, 2.71000000, 2.72000000, 2.73000000, 2.74000000, 2.75000000, 2.76000000, 2.77000000, 2.78000000, 2.79000000, 2.80000000, 2.81000000, 2.82000000, 2.83000000, 2.84000000, 2.85000000, 2.86000000, 2.87000000, 2.88000000, 2.89000000, 2.90000000, 2.91000000, 2.92000000, 2.93000000, 2.94000000, 2.95000000, 2.96000000, 2.97000000, 2.98000000, 2.99000000, 3.00000000, 3.01000000, 3.02000000, 3.03000000, 3.04000000, 3.05000000, 3.06000000, 3.07000000, 3.08000000, 3.09000000, 3.10000000, 3.11000000, 3.12000000, 3.13000000, 3.14000000, 3.15000000, 3.16000000, 3.17000000, 3.18000000, 3.19000000, 3.20000000, 3.21000000, 3.22000000, 3.23000000, 3.24000000, 3.25000000, 3.26000000, 3.27000000, 3.28000000, 3.29000000, 3.30000000, 3.31000000, 3.32000000, 3.33000000, 3.34000000, 3.35000000, 3.36000000, 3.37000000, 3.38000000, 3.39000000, 3.40000000, 3.41000000, 3.42000000, 3.43000000, 3.44000000, 3.45000000, 3.46000000, 3.47000000, 3.48000000, 3.49000000, 3.50000000, 3.51000000, 3.52000000, 3.53000000, 3.54000000, 3.55000000, 3.56000000, 3.57000000, 3.58000000, 3.59000000, 3.60000000, 3.61000000, 3.62000000, 3.63000000, 3.64000000, 3.65000000, 3.66000000, 3.67000000, 3.68000000, 3.69000000, 3.70000000, 3.71000000, 3.72000000, 3.73000000, 3.74000000, 3.75000000, 3.76000000, 3.77000000, 3.78000000, 3.79000000, 3.80000000, 3.81000000, 3.82000000, 3.83000000, 3.84000000, 3.85000000, 3.86000000, 3.87000000, 3.88000000, 3.89000000, 3.90000000, 3.91000000, 3.92000000, 3.93000000, 3.94000000, 3.95000000, 3.96000000, 3.97000000, 3.98000000, 3.99000000, 4.00000000, 4.01000000, 4.02000000, 4.03000000, 4.04000000, 4.05000000, 4.06000000, 4.07000000, 4.08000000, 4.09000000, 4.10000000, 4.11000000, 4.12000000, 4.13000000, 4.14000000, 4.15000000, 4.16000000, 4.17000000, 4.18000000, 4.19000000, 4.20000000, 4.21000000, 4.22000000, 4.23000000, 4.24000000, 4.25000000, 4.26000000, 4.27000000, 4.28000000, 4.29000000, 4.30000000, 4.31000000, 4.32000000, 4.33000000, 4.34000000, 4.35000000, 4.36000000, 4.37000000, 4.38000000, 4.39200000, 4.40200000, 4.41200000, 4.42200000, 4.43200000, 4.44200000, 4.45200000, 4.46200000, 4.47200000, 4.48200000, 4.49200000, 4.50200000, 4.51200000, 4.52200000, 4.53200000, 4.54200000, 4.55200000, 4.56200000, 4.57200000, 4.58200000, 4.59200000, 4.60200000, 4.61200000, 4.62200000, 4.63200000, 4.64200000, 4.65200000, 4.66200000, 4.67200000, 4.68200000, 4.69200000, 4.70200000, 4.71200000, 4.72200000, 4.73200000, 4.74200000, 4.75200000, 4.76200000, 4.77200000, 4.78200000, 4.79200000, 4.80200000, 4.81200000, 4.82200000, 4.83200000, 4.84200000, 4.85200000, 4.86200000, 4.87200000, 4.88200000, 4.89200000, 4.90200000, 4.91200000, 4.92200000, 4.93200000, 4.94200000, 4.95200000, 4.96200000, 4.97200000, 4.98200000, 4.99200000, 5.00200000, 5.01200000, 5.02200000, 5.03200000, 5.04200000, 5.05200000, 5.06200000, 5.07200000, 5.08200000, 5.09200000, 5.10200000, 5.11200000, 5.12200000, 5.13200000, 5.14200000, 5.15200000, 5.16200000, 5.17200000, 5.18200000, 5.19200000, 5.20200000, 5.21200000, 5.22200000, 5.23200000, 5.24200000, 5.25200000, 5.26200000, 5.27200000, 5.28200000, 5.29200000, 5.30200000])
y_arr = np.array([0.00166700, 0.01167000, 0.02167000, 0.03167000, 0.04167000, 0.05167000, 0.06167000, 0.07167000, 0.08167000, 0.09167000, 0.10170000, 0.11170000, 0.12170000, 0.13170000, 0.14170000, 0.15170000, 0.16170000, 0.17170000, 0.18170000, 0.19170000, 0.20170000, 0.21170000, 0.22170000, 0.23170000, 0.24170000, 0.25170000, 0.26170000, 0.27170000, 0.28170000, 0.29170000, 0.30170000, 0.31170000, 0.32170000, 0.33170000, 0.34170000, 0.35170000, 0.36170000, 0.37170000, 0.38170000, 0.39170000, 0.40170000, 0.41170000, 0.42170000, 0.43170000, 0.44170000, 0.45170000, 0.46170000, 0.47170000, 0.48170000, 0.49170000, 0.50170000, 0.51170000, 0.52170000, 0.53170000, 0.54170000, 0.55170000, 0.56170000, 0.57170000, 0.58170000, 0.59170000, 0.60170000, 0.61170000, 0.62170000, 0.63170000, 0.64170000, 0.65170000, 0.66170000, 0.67170000, 0.68170000, 0.69170000, 0.70170000, 0.71170000, 0.72170000, 0.73170000, 0.74170000, 0.75170000, 0.76170000, 0.77170000, 0.78170000, 0.79170000, 0.80170000, 0.81170000, 0.82170000, 0.83170000, 0.84170000, 0.85170000, 0.86170000, 0.87170000, 0.88170000, 0.89170000, 0.90170000, 0.91170000, 0.92170000, 0.93170000, 0.94170000, 0.95170000, 0.96170000, 0.97170000, 0.98170000, 0.99170000, 1.00200000, 1.01200000, 1.02200000, 1.03200000, 1.04200000, 1.05200000, 1.06200000, 1.07200000, 1.08200000, 1.09200000, 1.10200000, 1.11200000, 1.12200000, 1.13200000, 1.14200000, 1.15200000, 1.16200000, 1.17200000, 1.18200000, 1.19200000, 1.20200000, 1.21200000, 1.22200000, 1.23200000, 1.24200000, 1.25200000, 1.26200000, 1.27200000, 1.28200000, 1.29200000, 1.30200000, 1.31200000, 1.32200000, 1.33200000, 1.34200000, 1.35200000, 1.36200000, 1.37200000, 1.38200000, 1.39200000, 1.40200000, 1.41200000, 1.42200000, 1.43200000, 1.44200000, 1.45200000, 1.46200000, 1.47200000, 1.48200000, 1.49200000, 1.50200000, 1.51200000, 1.52200000, 1.53200000, 1.54200000, 1.55200000, 1.56200000, 1.57200000, 1.58200000, 1.59200000, 1.60200000, 1.61200000, 1.62200000, 1.63200000, 1.64200000, 1.65200000, 1.66200000, 1.67200000, 1.68200000, 1.69200000, 1.70200000, 1.71200000, 1.72200000, 1.73200000, 1.74200000, 1.75200000, 1.76200000, 1.77200000, 1.78200000, 1.79200000, 1.80200000, 1.81200000, 1.82200000, 1.83200000, 1.84200000, 1.85200000, 1.86200000, 1.87200000, 1.88200000, 1.89200000, 1.90200000, 1.91200000, 1.92200000, 1.93200000, 1.94200000, 1.95200000, 1.96200000, 1.97200000, 1.98200000, 1.99200000, 2.00200000, 2.01200000, 2.02200000, 2.03200000, 2.04200000, 2.05200000, 2.06200000, 2.07200000, 2.08200000, 2.09200000, 2.10200000, 2.11200000, 2.12200000, 2.13200000, 2.14200000, 2.15200000, 2.16200000, 2.17200000, 2.18200000, 2.19200000, 2.20200000, 2.21200000, 2.22200000, 2.23200000, 2.24200000, 2.25200000, 2.26200000, 2.27200000, 2.28200000, 2.29200000, 2.30200000, 2.31200000, 2.32200000, 2.33200000, 2.34200000, 2.35200000, 2.36200000, 2.37200000, 2.38200000, 2.39200000, 2.40200000, 2.41200000, 2.42200000, 2.43200000, 2.44200000, 2.45200000, 2.46200000, 2.47200000, 2.48200000, 2.49200000, 2.50200000, 2.51200000, 2.52200000, 2.53200000, 2.54200000, 2.55200000, 2.56200000, 2.57200000, 2.58200000, 2.59200000, 2.60200000, 2.61200000, 2.62200000, 2.63200000, 2.64200000, 2.65200000, 2.66200000, 2.67200000, 2.68200000, 2.69200000, 2.70200000, 2.71200000, 2.72200000, 2.73200000, 2.74200000, 2.75200000, 2.76200000, 2.77200000, 2.78200000, 2.79200000, 2.80200000, 2.81200000, 2.82200000, 2.83200000, 2.84200000, 2.85200000, 2.86200000, 2.87200000, 2.88200000, 2.89200000, 2.90200000, 2.91200000, 2.92200000, 2.93200000, 2.94200000, 2.95200000, 2.96200000, 2.97200000, 2.98200000, 2.99200000, 3.00200000, 3.01200000, 3.02200000, 3.03200000, 3.04200000, 3.05200000, 3.06200000, 3.07200000, 3.08200000, 3.09200000, 3.10200000, 3.11200000, 3.12200000, 3.13200000, 3.14200000, 3.15200000, 3.16200000, 3.17200000, 3.18200000, 3.19200000, 3.20200000, 3.21200000, 3.22200000, 3.23200000, 3.24200000, 3.25200000, 3.26200000, 3.27200000, 3.28200000, 3.29200000, 3.30200000, 3.31200000, 3.32200000, 3.33200000, 3.34200000, 3.35200000, 3.36200000, 3.37200000, 3.38200000, 3.39200000, 3.40200000, 3.41200000, 3.42200000, 3.43200000, 3.44200000, 3.45200000, 3.46200000, 3.47200000, 3.48200000, 3.49200000, 3.50200000, 3.51200000, 3.52200000, 3.53200000, 3.54200000, 3.55200000, 3.56200000, 3.57200000, 3.58200000, 3.59200000, 3.60200000, 3.61200000, 3.62200000, 3.63200000, 3.64200000, 3.65200000, 3.66200000, 3.67200000, 3.68200000, 3.69200000, 3.70200000, 3.71200000, 3.72200000, 3.73200000, 3.74200000, 3.75200000, 3.76200000, 3.77200000, 3.78200000, 3.79200000, 3.80200000, 3.81200000, 3.82200000, 3.83200000, 3.84200000, 3.85200000, 3.86200000, 3.87200000, 3.88200000, 3.89200000, 3.90200000, 3.91200000, 3.92200000, 3.93300000, 3.94300000, 3.95300000, 3.96300000, 3.97300000, 3.98300000, 3.99300000, 4.00300000, 4.01300000, 4.02300000, 4.03300000, 4.04300000, 4.05300000, 4.06300000, 4.07300000, 4.08300000, 4.09300000, 4.10300000, 4.11300000, 4.12300000, 4.13300000, 4.14300000, 4.15300000, 4.16300000, 4.17300000, 4.18300000, 4.19300000, 4.20300000, 4.21300000, 4.22300000, 4.23300000, 4.24300000, 4.25300000, 4.26300000, 4.27300000, 4.28300000, 4.29300000, 4.30300000, 4.31300000, 4.32300000, 4.33300000, 4.34300000, 4.35300000, 4.36300000, 4.37300000, 4.38300000, 4.39300000, 4.40300000, 4.41300000, 4.42300000, 4.43300000, 4.44300000, 4.45300000, 4.46300000, 4.47300000, 4.48300000, 4.49300000, 4.50300000, 4.51300000, 4.52300000, 4.53300000, 4.54300000, 4.55300000, 4.56300000, 4.57300000, 4.58300000, 4.59300000, 4.60300000, 4.61300000, 4.62300000, 4.63300000, 4.64300000, 4.65300000, 4.66300000, 4.67300000, 4.68300000, 4.69300000, 4.70300000, 4.71300000, 4.72300000, 4.73300000, 4.74300000, 4.75300000, 4.76300000, 4.77300000, 4.78300000, 4.79300000, 4.80300000, 4.81300000, 4.82300000, 4.83300000, 4.84300000, 4.85300000, 4.86300000, 4.87300000, 4.88300000, 4.89300000, 4.90300000, 4.91300000, 4.92300000, 4.93300000, 4.94300000, 4.95300000, 4.96300000, 4.97300000, 4.98300000, 4.99300000, 5.00300000, 5.01300000, 5.02300000, 5.03300000, 5.04300000, 5.05300000, 5.06300000, 5.07300000, 5.08300000, 5.09300000, 5.10300000, 5.11300000, 5.12300000, 5.13300000, 5.14300000, 5.15300000, 5.16300000, 5.17300000, 5.18300000, 5.19300000])
y_err = 0.5    # as a starting point
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
y_err_arr = rand.uniform(low=y_err * 0.9, high=y_err * 1.1, size=y_arr.size)
time_arr = time_arr[:y_arr.size]

p0 = (80, 50, -2e-2, -5e-4)
popt, perr = curve_fit(
    f=damped_osci,
    xdata=time_arr,
    ydata=y_arr,
    sigma=y_err_arr,
    p0=(0, 0, 1, 1),
    maxfev=100_000,
)
print(popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax: plt.Axes
ax.fill_between(x=time_arr, alpha=0.3, label='experiment error',
                y1=y_arr - y_err_arr,
                y2=y_arr + y_err_arr)
ax.plot(time_arr, y_arr, label='experiment')
ax.plot(time_arr, damped_osci(time_arr, *p0), label='guess')
ax.plot(time_arr, damped_osci(time_arr, *popt), label='fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

> Does the passing of the measurement error to the fit via `sigma=y_err_arr` mean that the returned `perr` handles the error propagation correctly? In which way? Unfortunately the scipy documentation says nothing about the math used.

Read [the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L610); to start:

```
    sigma : None or scalar or M-length sequence or MxM array, optional
        Determines the uncertainty in `ydata`. If we define residuals as
        ``r = ydata - f(xdata, *popt)``, then the interpretation of `sigma`
        depends on its number of dimensions:

            - A scalar or 1-D `sigma` should contain values of standard deviations of
              errors in `ydata`. In this case, the optimized function is
              ``chisq = sum((r / sigma) ** 2)``.

            - A 2-D `sigma` should contain the covariance matrix of
              errors in `ydata`. In this case, the optimized function is
              ``chisq = r.T @ inv(sigma) @ r``.

              .. versionadded:: 0.19

        None (default) is equivalent of 1-D `sigma` filled with ones.
    absolute_sigma : bool, optional
        If True, `sigma` is used in an absolute sense and the estimated parameter
        covariance `pcov` reflects these absolute values.

        If False (default), only the relative magnitudes of the `sigma` values matter.
        The returned parameter covariance matrix `pcov` is based on scaling
        `sigma` by a constant factor. This constant is set by demanding that the
        reduced `chisq` for the optimal parameters `popt` when using the
        *scaled* `sigma` equals unity. In other words, `sigma` is scaled to
        match the sample variance of the residuals after the fit. Default is False.
        Mathematically,
        ``pcov(absolute_sigma=False) = pcov(absolute_sigma=True) * chisq(popt)/(M-N)``
```

The mode used in the sample above is `absolute_sigma=False`, which means that the resulting `pcov` scales `sigma` based on the residuals - so `curve_fit` *does* "handle the error propagation", and in my mind correctly.

If you're paranoid about the results you can also examine `infodict['fvec']`:

```
        ``fvec``
            The residual values evaluated at the solution, for a 1-D `sigma`
            this is ``(f(x, *popt) - ydata)/sigma``.
```

Transformation of `sigma` is handled [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L937).

Comment: Thanks! Does the passing of the measurement error to the fit via *sigma=y_err_arr* mean that the returned *perr* handles the error propagation correctly? In which way? Unfortunately the scipy documentation says nothing about the math used.

Comment: @TomS The documentation actually says basically everything about the math used, and you can read the source as well (I added some links to the answer).

Comment: thanks a lot for you help and clarification; seems to work as expected.